# INST:07545:Unexpected error.java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: installation, location, oracle-home

while installing (oracle fusion middleware 12c infrastructure installation) getting INST:07545:Unexpected error.java.lang.NullPointerException  fail to create
folder in C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home

[image]

Answer (score 7):

*You can set up new temp dir and restart installation process.*

```
**1.** Create a new Temp directory.

eg:
E:\Temp
**2.** Set temp environment variable as

set TEMP=E:\Temp
set TMP=E:\Temp
**3.** Start the installer from the same prompt as

java -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls.jar
OR

Installer can be started using the command

java -Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\Temp -jar fmw_12.2.1.4.0_wls.jar
```

Comment: @Dhiraj, I was going through this and had issue so thought of answering. Anyway please mark accepted so it would help others too. Thanks.

Comment: This solution worked for me however I also needed to downgrade the java version to 1.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes because there is not enough space available in your default temp folder. If you are on windows and there is a drive with more space available then you can create temp folder there and use that for installation. For specifying a different temp folder you can go to environment variables and change the temp and tmp variables to point to new location.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your point but mine was an item before opening pop up `Installation Location` and was a kind of `java.lang.NullPointerException at oracle.jdeveloper.model.ApplicationContent.getInstance(ApplicationContent.java:62`

I went to and got in:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\systemSomeVersion\
```

backed up  `o.ide` folder and deleted it, relaunched IDE and now it plays ok again